# Cambiar nombre de imágenes copiadas del servidor con PHP

Tags: php

tengo una función en PHP que lo que hace es simplemente recibir valores de un Ajax y crear una carpeta en el servidor, copiar los archivos de una carpeta llamada "temp" y luego moverlos a la carpeta nueva que se creo en el servidor para luego limpiar la carpeta "temp"...

```
function crear_carpeta($datos){

$carpeta = '../informes/'.$datos['newCarpeta'];

if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
    mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
}

$data = $datos['newCarpeta'];

$from = '../temp/';
$to = '../informes/'.$data;

//Abro el directorio que voy a leer
$dir = opendir($from);

//Recorro el directorio para leer los archivos que tiene
while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false){
    //Leo todos los archivos excepto . y ..
    if(strpos($file, '.') !== 0){
        //Copio el archivo manteniendo el mismo nombre en la nueva carpeta
        copy($from.'/'.$file, $to.'/'.$file);
    }
}

$files = glob('../temp/*'); // obtiene todos los archivos
foreach($files as $file){
  if(is_file($file)) // si se trata de un archivo
    unlink($file); // lo elimina
}

$respuesta = 1;
return $respuesta;
}
```

Por lo que la pregunta entonces seria la siguiente... ¿Como hago para que dentro de esta misma función yo pueda cambiar los nombres de cada documento?

Porque hasta ahora la función solo los copia con sus nombres que son números a partir del "0"... Pero y si por ejemplo quisiera que el archivo se copiara con el nombre que este en la posición 0 de un array que tengo?; como este

```
$datos['amarillo.png','azul.jpg','rojo.jpg','verde.png','vinotinto.jpg','morado.png']; //EJEMPLO
```

Comment: En el segundo parámetro de `copy` puedes indicar el nombre del fichero final, no tiene por que ser el mismo. También puedes utilizar la función `rename()`

Comment: Ya lo reemplace por rename(); pero la pregunta esta es... si tengo rename($from.'/'.$file, $to.'/'.$file); y yo cambio el ultimo parametro de $file por el nombre que deseo, ¿me cambiara la extension? o ¿solo el nombre?

Comment: En el rename pones la ruta del fichero completa, no solo lo que tu quieres cambiar. Si el fichero es en /temp/ejemplo.tmp y lo quieres pasar a /temp/renombrado.xml, tendrás que llamar al rename con esas rutas completas: `rename('/temp/ejemplo.tmp', '/temp/renombrado.xml')`

Comment: no me sirve asi, lo siento y gracias por la ayuda @JaviMollá

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te hice saber en los comentarios puedes utilizar la misma función [`copy()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.copy.php) para que el archivo copiado final tenga el nombre que tu desees. También usaremos [`pathinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.pathinfo.php) para obtener la extension inicial del archivo.

Ejemplo usando tu mismo código:

```
<?php

function crear_carpeta($datos){

    // definir path
    $from = '../temp/';
    $to   = '../informes/'.$datos['newCarpeta'];
    $name = 'NOMBRE_MIS_ARCHIVOS_FINALES_SIN_EXTENSION';

    // comprobar si la ruta de destino existe 
    // y crearla si no existe
    if ( !file_exists($to) ) {
        mkdir($to, 0777, true);
    }

    //Abro el directorio que voy a leer
    $dir = opendir($from);

    // creamos un contador
    $i = 0;

    //Recorro el directorio para leer los archivos que tiene
    //Leo todos los archivos excepto . y ..
    while( ($file = readdir($dir)) !== false ){
        if( strpos($file, '.') !== 0 ){
            // optenemos la extension del archivo
            $extension = pathinfo($from.'/'.$file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            // copiamos el archivo con el nombre que definimos en $name anteponiendo el contador
            // y mantenemos la misma extensión
            copy($from.'/'.$file, $to.'/'.$i.'_'.$name.'.'.$extension);
            ++$i;
        }
    }

    $files = glob('../temp/*'); // obtiene todos los archivos
    foreach($files as $file){
      if(is_file($file)) // si se trata de un archivo
        unlink($file); // lo elimina
    }

    $respuesta = 1;
    return $respuesta;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo para mover ficheros de un form uso la siguiente funcion:

```
$documento=$_FILES['documentos']['tmp_name'];
$info = new SplFileInfo($_FILES['documentos']['name']);
$directorio='../documentos/documentos/'."el nombre que te de la gana".$info->getExtension();
move_uploaded_file($documento,$directorio);
```

supongo que podrás adaptarla a tu código, si no entre los dos lo hacemos

Comment: el codigo que ya tengo funciona perfecto, lo unico que quiero hacer es reemplazar el nombre de cada archivo, por ejemplo que el primer archivo que tome se llame uno.png y el segundo dos.jpe, los nombres yo los tengo en un array pero no se como introducirlos al while